# Help needed with PPPoE interface on Juniper MX104

Tags: ipv4, juniper, pppoe

I've been trying to configure dynamic subscriber management on MX104 and pretty much succeeded too. The problem I am facing now is, the MX is listening for and responding to PADI but as soon as it sends PADS, it also sends PADT, thereby terminating the connection and there is no errors in pppoe statistics.

Here is the complete configuration:

```
version 13.3R1.8;
dynamic-profiles {
    LE-profile {
        interfaces {
            pp0 {
                unit "$junos-interface-unit" {
                    ppp-options {
                        pap;
                    }
                    pppoe-options {
                        underlying-interface "$junos-underlying-interface";
                        server;
                    }
                    keepalives interval 30;
                    family inet {
                        filter {
                            input "$junos-input-filter";
                            output "$junos-output-filter";
                        }
                        unnumbered-address lo0.0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
system {
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "*********************"; ## SECRET-D     ATA
    }
    syslog {
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any notice;
            authorization info;
        }
        file interactive-commands {
            interactive-commands any;
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        vlan-tagging;
        unit 800 {
            encapsulation ppp-over-ether;
            vlan-id 800;
            pppoe-underlying-options {
                dynamic-profile LE-profile;
            }
        }
        unit 900 {
            encapsulation ppp-over-ether;
            vlan-id 900;
            pppoe-underlying-options {
                dynamic-profile LE-profile;
            }
        }
    }
    fxp0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.10.10.10/24;
            }
        }
    }
    lo0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 90.90.90.1/32;
            }
        }
    }
}
firewall {
    family inet {
        filter MONTHLY_4096_OUT {
            interface-specific;
            term 1 {
                then {
                    policer MONTHLY_4096_POLICER;
                    accept;
                }
            }
        }
        filter MONTHLY_4096_IN {
            interface-specific;
            term 1 {
                then {
                    policer MONTHLY_256K_POLICER;
                    accept;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    policer MONTHLY_4096_POLICER {
        if-exceeding {
            bandwidth-limit 4m;
            burst-size-limit 100k;
        }
        then discard;
    }
    policer MONTHLY_256K_POLICER {
        if-exceeding {
            bandwidth-limit 1m;
            burst-size-limit 128k;
        }
        then discard;
    }
}
access {
    radius-server {
        10.10.10.111 {
            secret "*******************"; ## SECRET-DATA
            source-address 10.10.10.10;
        }
    }
    profile RAD {
        accounting-order radius;
        authentication-order radius;
        radius {
            authentication-server 10.10.10.111;
            accounting-server 10.10.10.111;
            options {
                nas-identifier 10.10.10.10;
            }
        }
    }
    address-assignment {
        pool VJ-POOL {
            family inet {
                network 10.170.0.0/15;
                range 1 {
                    low 10.170.0.10;
                    high 10.171.255.252;
                }
                dhcp-attributes {
                    maximum-lease-time 86400;
                    name-server {
                        8.8.8.8;
                    }
                    router {
                        10.170.0.1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

[image: PPPoE Statistics from MX104]

Comment: Is this a new implementation, or something that you changed and has stopped working?  Can you get a packet capture or turn on trace options so we can see what the cause of termination is?

Comment: How about adding chap under ppp-options?

Comment: It's a completely new configuration. I haven't configured traceoptions yet but it looks like it will be a good idea.

Comment: i have setup a freeradius for pap authentication but it won't hurt to add chap under ppp-options. I'll do that too with traceoptions.

Comment: I took a wireshark capture and it seems the switch is not tagging the VLAN id on the PADI and PADR packets... I will update

Comment: apparently the EX4300 that I have is removing the VLAN tag which is necessary since the configuration on MX requires that the packets coming from switch are tagged with VLAN id 800 or 900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorry for posting it too late but as it turns out, the NAS wasn't able to make a connection to the RADIUS due to the firewall and hence all the requests were being rejected. We fixed the iptables rules on RADIUS and the same dynamic profile is working now.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.